# sap.m.MultiComboBox: How to get texts from all selected items?

Tags: sapui5

After `selectionFinish`, I would like to get all the selected item texts from the list. The usual approach of getting all the selected items goes like this:

```js
this.byId("idExampleMultiComboBox").getSelectedItems();
```

**Issue:** It returns objects of type `sap.ui.core.Item` with all the aggregations/associations. I only need the text of the selected option.

MultiComboBox:

```xml
<MultiComboBox id="idExampleMultiComboBox"
  items="{modelExample>/}"
  selectionFinish=".onSelectionFinish">
  <core:ListItem text="{modelExample>Option}" />
</MultiComboBox>
```

```js
let modelExample = {
  0: { "Option": "ExampleOption1" },
  1: { "Option": "ExampleOption2" }
};
```

**One approach:**

```js
onSelectionFinish: function(oEvent){
  let aSelectedCriteria = [];
  let i = 0;
  while (i < oEvent.getSource().getSelectedItems().length) {
    aSelectedCriteria.push(oEvent.getSource().getSelectedItems()[i].getText())
    i = i + 1;
  }
},
```

**Question:** How to get the selected Items as Text from the list?

Comment: What would you do with the bunch of texts? What are you trying to achieve? Usually, the entries should have uniquely identifiable values which should be bound to `key` of the `(List)Item` and then to `selectedKeys` of the `MultiComboBox`. Selecting from the dropdown list will automatically update the `selectedKeys` property thanks to the TwoWay binding. You can then access the selected keys from anywhere without having to go through a control reference or without having to listen to `selectionFinish`.

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann, the thing is, a selectedKeys="", should be declared in the very first place with a model bound to it. Those the twoway binding will work if it is already bound to a model, i wanted to avoid that. What would you do with the bunch of texts? - Needed it to have an array with all the selected option as strings/texts not objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My recommendation: Use the [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to create an array of all texts. This is simply your approach with a more convenient method.

```js
onSelectionFinish: function(oEvent) {
  const aSelectedItems = oEvent.getParameter("selectedItems");
  const aSelectedTexts = aSelectedItems.map(oItem => oItem.getText());
},
```

---

Another approach would be to only get the selected keys and then loop over your model instead.

```js
onSelectionFinish: function(oEvent) {
  // There are multiple ways to retrieve your model
  const oModel = oEvent.getSource().getBinding("items").getModel();
  const aSelectedKeys = oEvent.getSource().getSelectedKeys();
  const aSelectedCriteria = aSelectedKeys.map(sKey => oModel.getProperty("/" + sKey);
},
```